# Bubble sort implementation to sort arrays. How effecient?

Tags: java

I sorted an array using an algorithm and when I was going trough a book. The algorithm that I wrote had a name **(BUBBLE SORT)** . I was wondering if the program I roughly wrote implemented the bubble sort algorithm perfectly or is there a more efficient way of doing the same?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Tool {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] n = {4,8,12,87,32,98,12,45,94,42,938,84,63,67,86,37};
        int inter = 0;

        int arrayLength = n.length;

        int pass = arrayLength-1;
        for(int y = 0; y < arrayLength - 1; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < pass; x++) {
                if(n[x] < n[x + 1]) {
                    inter = n[x];
                    n[x] = n[x + 1];
                    n[x + 1] = inter;
                    num++;
                }

            }
            pass--;
        }
        // To print the resulting array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));
    }
}
```

Comment: [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good website to look for algorithm implementation is http://www.algolist.com. You can find the article on bubble sort [here](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort).

It looks like your code is lacking an optimization that checks if swapping is actually necessary (as Loki Astari noted).

This code is taken from the above URL, which implements this optimization:

```java
public void bubbleSort(int[] arr){
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp;
    while(swapped){
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - j; i++){
            if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1]){
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it from that page, it has helpful diagrams too if you're more of a visual learner (like myself).

Cheers

Comment: +1 for actually addressing OP's question instead of whether bubble sort is an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking that is not an implementation of the bubble sort algorithm. It's an implementation of an improved version of the bubble sort, however, it's not implemented correctly.

The implementation uses the fact that the last item is known to be at the right position after the first pass, so the next pass can sort one less item. The original bubble sort algorithm just loops through all items all the time.

What's missing is that the algorithm doesn't check for when there are no more swaps made, instead it keeps looping until it reached the maximum number of iterations is reached that would be needed in the worst possible case. That means that it will usually keep looping long after everything is already sorted. There is a variable `num` that seems to be intended for this, but there is something wrong because that variable is not declared anywhere.

You should initialise `num` to zero before the inner loop, and loop until it is still zero after looping through the items:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Tool {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] n={4,8,12,87,32,98,12,45,94,42,938,84,63,67,86,37};

    int pass = n.length - 1;
    int num;
    do {
      num = 0;

      for(int x = 0; x < pass; x++){
        if(n[x] < n[x + 1]){
          int temp = n[x];
          n[x] = n[x + 1];
          n[x + 1] = temp
          num++;
        }

      }
      pass--;

    } while (num != 0);
    // To print the resulting array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n));

  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually addressing OP's question instead of whether bubble sort is an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

See.

> **Bubble** sort, also known as **sinking** sort, is a simple sorting algorithm that works by repeatedly stepping through the list to be sorted, comparing each pair of adjacent items and swapping them if they are in the wrong order. The pass through the list is repeated until no swaps are needed, which indicates that the list is sorted. The algorithm gets its name from the way smaller elements "bubble" to the top of the list. Because it only uses comparisons to operate on elements, it is a comparison sort. Although the algorithm is simple, it is not efficient for sorting large lists; other algorithms are better. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)
>
> Bubble sort has worst-case and average complexity both О(n2), where n
>   is the number of items being sorted. There exist many sorting
>   algorithms with substantially better worst-case or average complexity
>   of O(n log n). Even other О(n2) sorting algorithms, such as insertion
>   sort, tend to have better performance than bubble sort. Therefore,
>   bubble sort is not a practical sorting algorithm when n is large.
>
> The only significant advantage that bubble sort has over most other
>   implementations, even quicksort, but not insertion sort, is that the
>   ability to detect that the list is sorted is efficiently built into
>   the algorithm. Performance of bubble sort over an already-sorted list
>   (best-case) is O(n). By contrast, most other algorithms, even those
>   with better average-case complexity, perform their entire sorting
>   process on the set and thus are more complex. However, not only does
>   insertion sort have this mechanism too, but it also performs better on
>   a list that is substantially sorted (having a small number of
>   inversions).
>
> The positions of the elements in bubble sort will play a large part in determining its performance. Large elements at the beginning of the list do not pose a problem, as they are quickly swapped. Small elements towards the end, however, move to the beginning extremely slowly.
>
> The Jargon file, which famously calls bogosort "the archetypical perversely awful algorithm", also calls bubble sort "the generic bad algorithm".[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) Donald Knuth, in his famous book The Art of Computer Programming, concluded that "the bubble sort seems to have nothing to recommend it, except a catchy name.
>
> Bubble sort also interacts poorly with modern CPU hardware. It requires at least twice as many writes as insertion sort, twice as many cache misses.
>
> **in Java show bubble sort to be roughly 5 times slower than [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and 40% slower than [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)**.

Comment: Nothing apart from it is easy to write correctly. If I have twenty items to sort (and no standard sort algorithm) I am more likely to write a Bubble Sort (and a comment rewrite) than any of the others because of its simplicity.

Comment: That's right. When we have short lists, we should stick at the *bubble sort* because in that case performance is not a critical issue because of the simplicity of the lists but when we have long list of elements to be sorted, this approach is not well-suited and it must be avoided.

Comment: The difference between algorithmic complexities of O(N**2) and O(N**log(N)) isn't linear. You can't make statements like '5 times slower'.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is basically O(n^2)  (Note: This is one of the worst complexities for sorting).

There is a small optimization if a run through inner loop does not produce any swaps then you can break out of the outter loops as this is an indication that the array is completely sorted. Which gives you a best case of O(n) for already sorted data (though I don't think its called O for best case).

Comment: Not exactly. You can't break out of both loops, you have to complete the inner loop before knowing that you can know that there are no more swaps.

Comment: If you're not familiar with what O(n^2) means, time it for an array of 1000 random numbers, then 10,000, then 100,000, 1,000,000 etc... It will get much slower as the amount of work it has to do goes up.

Comment: What @bill means is: O(n^2) means the execution time is related to the square of the number of elements.